# Linux Domain Controller

Tags: linux, ldap

I'm kinda new in the admin scenario. I'm looking for a good source where to study in deep what a domain is and how to manage it. The point is that I'm a tlc eng but I don't have any experience in it. At work I'm handling Active Directories, and I was wondering what is the correspondence in Linux, and where to get all the knowledge for it.

Any suggestion? Moreover do you have a good source where to study CIDR? :D 
thank you

Comment: To learn about CIDR and subnetting, the answer is in [this thread](http://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-subnetting-work) on SF. It has great answers that explain everything you want to know about :)

Comment: In the future, if you have two separate questions, please be sure to ask them separately.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a Linux server serve as a Domain Controller for Windows Machines?](http://serverfault.com/questions/29236/can-a-linux-server-serve-as-a-domain-controller-for-windows-machines)

Comment: Well I'm more interested in the theory of it, so how it works and so on... cause I'm missing the theory not the practice :D

Comment: We don't mind multiple related questions but your two aren't and as you can see the answers provided only answer one or the other which really doesn't work on an Q&A site.

Answer (score 3):

What you are probably looking for is Samba 4:
  http://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba4

Answer (score 1):

Something like [FreeIPA](http://freeipa.org/page/Main_Page) is the closest parallel to Active Directory on the Linux side, as it combines DNS, directory services, centralized authentication, etc.